# Vectorised index of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Originally I had something like this:

```py
a = 1   # Some randomly generated positive integer
b = -1  # Some randomly generated negative integer
c = 0   # Constant 0

i = 0  # Randomly picked from (0, 1, 2)

d = [a, b, c][i]
```

I would like to vectorise this so that many samples can be generated

So I have three arrays of length N, an index array of length N, and would like to use that index array to pick one of the three arrays

```py
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([-1, -2, -3, -4])
c = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])

i = np.array([2, 1, 2, 0])

d = np.array([a, b, c])[i]  # Doesn't work
# Would like the result:
d = np.array([0, -2, 0, 4])
```

`d = a * (i == 0) + b * (i == 1) + c * (i == 2)` works, but surely there is a way that looks more like the unvectorised code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a 2-d array from the three arrays then use [Integer indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)

```
>>> e = np.vstack([a,b,c])
>>> i = np.array([2, 1, 2, 0])
>>> e[(i,np.arange(i.shape[0]))]
array([ 0, -2,  0,  4])
>>>
```

Comment: My original code has a `size` parameter that could be `None` for the non-vectorised version, which this can be extended nicely to `np.vstack([a, b, c])[(i, 0 if size is None else np.arange(size))]`. Thanks! (Though this doesn't extend to `size=[shape_0, shape_1]`)

Comment: @frankden -  `size=[shape_0, shape_1]` - resulting in three 2-d arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your answer is on the diagonal of

```
 np.array([a, b, c])[i]
```

so you can go:

```
 np.array([a, b, c])[i].diagonal()
```